# Extracting form field data from Adobe Signed (e-signed) Acroforms using Python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, data-extraction, form-fields

I am trying to extract field names and the corresponding field values from an **e-signed PDF form**, which I uploaded onto **Adobe Sign** and obtained e-signatures.
See link: https://documentcloud.adobe.com/us/en/.

Prior to uploading the PDF form, it was an Acroform i.e. an editable PDF which contained form fields.

From the Acroform PDF, I was able to extract the field name and field values using PDFTK. Furthermore, after signing this form on Adobe Reader, although the PDF is no longer editable (fields become locked), I could still use PDFTK to extract data from the PDF document.

However, after using **Adobe Sign** to request and obtain signatures, I am struggling to extract field names and values using PDFTK and Python. Adobe Sign does separately provide the form fields, but I am looking for a solution that uses Python (which can include shell commands like PDFTK within the .py script) to extract the field names & values from the e-signed PDF doc itself.

Would anyone be able to provide a solution using **Python** on extracting the field names and its corresponding values for this document (including fields that are left empty)?

Attempted on the following Adobe Signed PDF form:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1r57yrPuvzYlXwg-0KPM9UQGhu8jgWcUs/view?usp=sharing (signed using Adobe Sign)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/12NUyk7Jku4O1owBboyiCmk2ckpq8g26T/view?usp=sharing (no signature)

I tried this for another Acroform as well, but faced the same issue.
https://www.pruadviser.co.uk/pdf/PIPF10000.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to extract the field names or values from the Adobe Signed PDF because the document ***no longer has*** fields. It's a "flattened" PDF. The only field in the document is the digital signature field that holds the certification. Your only option is to use the Adobe Sign API to GET the field data as a CSV file at...

/agreements/{agreementId}/formData

Comment: 1) Is it possible at all to "unflatten" the PDF to regain the form fields?
2) Could you please give me further details on how to use the Adobe Sign API to get the field data and obtain the agreement ID for a large set of e-signed PDFs?
3) What's the full length of the address for /agreements/{agreementId}/formData?
4) Do you have any suggestions on extracting a "flat" PDF form's form names and values using Python? (This is in the event that the PDF form provided is "flattened" and the form data cannot be accessed or given).

Comment: 1) No. Not possible.
2) You can find that here https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6;jsessionid=CFDC0B377AD124CE9C1583BD4F7059A9.app-b18#!/agreements/getFormData
3) See above
4) A flattened form has no fields. That's what flat means.

When I wrote that using the Sign API was your only option, I meant ***only***.

Comment: Funny how Adobe Sign appears to have slightly changed appearances, though, e.g. the check marks are larger than before. Nonetheless one remark, you can try and extract field values from the signed PDF _if you also have an unsigned version of the PDF_ (unfilled or differently filled); then you can iterate over the field and widget definitions in the unsigned PDF and apply text extraction to the areas in the signed document which correspond to the field widget areas.

Comment: @mkl - Yes. The appearance generators for Acrobat and Adobe Sign are a bit different.